# Combine large files in Blobstore GAE FileNotOpenedError: ApplicationError: 10

Tags: google-app-engine, merge, blobstore

I'm trying merge 2 files and to create one new in the BlobStore of the AppEngine. This files are 12.000 rows and have 12 MB. The problem occurs when i writte the new file, because in middle of write appear the next error:

```
ApplicationError: 10 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 716, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ono-hat-vv2/1.369681903434492066/com/__init__.py", line 244, in post
    self.principal(cont+1, numFicheritos,"csvTotal","uniendoCSV")
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ono-hat-vv2/1.369681903434492066/com/__init__.py", line 277, in principal
    self.escribirtxt(f, cadenaSalida)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ono-hat-vv2/1.369681903434492066/com/__init__.py", line 308, in escribirtxt
    f.write(linea)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 326, in write
    self._make_rpc_call_with_retry('Append', request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 427, in _make_rpc_call_with_retry
    _make_call(method, request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 252, in _make_call
    _raise_app_error(e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 195, in _raise_app_error
    raise FileNotOpenedError(e)
FileNotOpenedError: ApplicationError: 10
```

I have read that the problem is in the time that I open the file, because this can't be greater that 30 s. How can i resolve this problem and merge this file?

Comment: You will probably have to show the code.

Comment: Maybe you could make a deferred task or work in a background

Comment: The problem was that the flow could not be much open time, and automatically closed. At the end I added the files to the cloud Storage that has fewer limitations and is easier to use

Answer (score 0):

Close the file and re-open every so often.

Have you looked at Google Cloud Storage? It may not have this limitation and also the app engine files api has been deprecated and we need to move in that direction anyway. Something to consider.

Comment: The problem was that the flow could not be much open time, and automatically closed. At the end I added the files to the cloud Storage that has fewer limitations and is easier to use